# How to improve: My parents were expecting a girl but me is what they got

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-choice

Any recommendations as to how to make that sentence sound a bit more 18th-century-screenplay like?

"me", as in being a male. (kind of like, they got stuck with me as a boy)

"My parents were expecting a girl but me is what they had to resign/conform with"?

EDIT: (A bit more context)

Andrea: Rene Maria Smith. Rene isn't a name that makes justice to you.

Rene: My parents were expecting a girl but me is what they got. It's the name of a destine my parents would've wanted for me.

Andrea: And in my home, I showed up while my mother really wanted a boy.

Comment: In my language we often say something like *my parents were expecting a girl but **it is what it is***, based on your example. I wonder what's the way native speakers state such sentence.

Comment: 18th century England?  They didn't have "screens" back then :-)

Comment: TRomano, terrible joke :D

Comment: Ustanak, I think **_it is what it is_** would still be correct, but I would say it's a much more modern expression, or at least I'd think so. So because of that not really what I was looking for.

Comment: "...but me is what they got" - sounds correct when spoken in a Yoda voice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My parents were expecting a girl but **I was** what they had to resign **themselves to**

**I** - because **I** is the subject of the second independent clause
**was** - because being born was in the past
**themselves** - reflexive pronoun indicating your parents
**to** - one resigns themselves **to** *something* not **with**

> My parents were expecting a girl but **got stuck with me as a boy**
>   My parents were expecting a girl but **only got me**

Both are perfectly acceptable and have the same meaning :)

Answer (score 5):

> ...but got me instead

would be idiomatic.